# How to execute expect script within docker container

Tags: bash, docker, expect

I have an expect script that I would like to run within docker container. I have named the file with exp extension and calling the file as filename.exp. I'm using Ubuntu docker image. Looks like container is able to recognize file when it starts with #!/usr/bin/env bash and not #!/usr/bin/expect

pipeline.yml file

```
jobs:
  - name: job-pass-files
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: resource-tutorial
      - task: create-some-files
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source: {repository: ubuntu}

          inputs:
            - name: resource-tutorial

          run:
            path: resource-tutorial/filename.exp
```

filename.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@****
#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "Password\r"
interact
```

I get following error when I execute job in concourse

```
Backend error: Exit status: 500, message: {"Type":"","Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"no such file or directory\"\n","Handle":"","ProcessID":"","Binary":""}
```

Is there a way to execute expect script from Docker container. Is there an image that supports that? I'm new to docker so any help is very appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just make a bash script that calls the expect script since you say "#!/usr/bin/env bash" is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an expect script to install a program that requires user prompts in one of my 16.04 Ubuntu containers.  Make sure to install the expect binary, it's not included.  Here's what it looks like:

Dockerfile:

```
<snip>

#Install yocto dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
  build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \
  xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping python3-git python3-jinja2 libegl1-mesa libsdl1.2-dev \
  xterm repo expect locales

# Install
RUN /home/docker/scripts/install.exp

<snip>
```

install.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

<snip>
```